# Three HTML dropdowns, where some options get disabled depending on earlier selections

Tags: javascript, html, form

I am making several dropdowns dependent on each other.

**Data** used to form dropdowns:

```
const data = {
    size: [ 
      { id: "s1", value: "009" },
      { id: "s2", value: "012" },
      { id: "s3", value: "041", configId: ["c2"], dischargeId: ["d3"] },
    ],
    config: [
      { id: "c1", value: "Horizontal", sizeId: ["s1", "s2"], dischargeId: ["d1", "d2"] },
      { id: "c2", value: "Vertical", dischargeId: ["d3"] },
    ],
     discharge: [
      {id: "d1", value: "S-Straight", sizeId: ["s1", "s2"], configId: ["c1"] },
      {id: "d2", value: "E-End", sizeId: ["s1", "s2"], configId: ["c1"] },
      {id: "d3", value: "T-Top", configId: ["c2"] },
    ]
}
```

Here if you see that some of the objects have some additional properties.

**Explanation:**

-> Under size, the third element with id `s3` has additional properties like `configId: ["c2"]` and `dischargeId: ["d3"]` .

So based on the above statement if the configuration dropdown is changed with config id `c1` (Horizontal), then size with id `s3` needs to be disabled.

Same way if it has `dischargeId` as `d1` or `d2`, then the size with id `s3` will be disabled. Like this the logics will go for other properties as well.

**Requirement:**

Here implementation-wise things are working fine, but I feel the code is repeated a lot for checking the conditions for all the properties as the data values (like size, config, discharge, ... , ... , ... , ...) may add further in the future. So is there any optimized way to make this code not repeat much and have it simple and clean with minimal lines?

```js
const data = {
    size: [ 
      { id: "s1", value: "009" },
      { id: "s2", value: "012" },
      { id: "s3", value: "041", configId: ["c2"], dischargeId: ["d3"] },
    ],
    config: [
      { id: "c1", value: "Horizontal", sizeId: ["s1", "s2"], dischargeId: ["d1", "d2"] },
      { id: "c2", value: "Vertical", dischargeId: ["d3"] },
    ],
     discharge: [
      {id: "d1", value: "S-Straight", sizeId: ["s1", "s2"], configId: ["c1"] },
      {id: "d2", value: "E-End", sizeId: ["s1", "s2"], configId: ["c1"] },
      {id: "d3", value: "T-Top", configId: ["c2"] },
    ]
}

const sizeSelect = document.getElementById('size')
const configSelect = document.getElementById('configuration')
const dischargeSelect = document.getElementById('discharge')

const createSelect = (values, select) => {
  values.forEach(t => {
    let opt = document.createElement('option')
    opt.value = t.id
    opt.text = t.value
    select.append(opt)
  })
}

createSelect(data.size, sizeSelect)
createSelect(data.config, configSelect)
createSelect(data.discharge, dischargeSelect)

sizeSelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const val = e.target.value
  const size = data.size.find(t => t.id == val)
  if(size.configId){
  Array.from(configSelect.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach(o => o.disabled = true)
  size.configId.forEach(sId =>
    configSelect.querySelector(`option[value="${sId}"]`).disabled = false)
  }
  if(size.dischargeId){
  Array.from(dischargeSelect.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach(o => o.disabled = true)
  size.dischargeId.forEach(sId =>
    dischargeSelect.querySelector(`option[value="${sId}"]`).disabled = false)
  }
});

configSelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const val = e.target.value
  const config = data.config.find(s => s.id == val)
  if(config.sizeId){
    Array.from(configSelect.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach(o => o.disabled = false)
    Array.from(sizeSelect.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach(o => o.disabled = true);
    config.sizeId.forEach(sId =>
    sizeSelect.querySelector(`option[value="${sId}"]`).disabled = false)
  }
  if(config.dischargeId){
  Array.from(dischargeSelect.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach(o => o.disabled = true)
  config.dischargeId.forEach(sId =>
    dischargeSelect.querySelector(`option[value="${sId}"]`).disabled = false)
  }
});

dischargeSelect.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  const val = e.target.value
  const discharge = data.discharge.find(s => s.id == val)
  if(discharge.sizeId){
    Array.from(sizeSelect.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach(o => o.disabled = true);
    discharge.sizeId.forEach(sId =>
    sizeSelect.querySelector(`option[value="${sId}"]`).disabled = false);
  }
  if(discharge.configId) {
    Array.from(configSelect.querySelectorAll('option')).forEach(o => o.disabled = true);
    discharge.configId.forEach(sId =>
    configSelect.querySelector(`option[value="${sId}"]`).disabled = false);
  }
});
```

```html
<select id="size"></select>
<select id="configuration"></select>
<select id="discharge"></select>
```